# Delphi Tokyo - IOS statusbar font colour

Tags: ios, delphi

Does anyone know how to set the status bar font colour to white on ios using delphi?

i have tried updating the plist file and calling

```
TUIApplication.Wrap(TUIApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication).setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyleLightContent);
```

but nothing changes when I do so. I am running Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1

Comment: Check that the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance entry actually appears in the deployed .plist file.

Comment: yes it does appear